# Determine media type/mime of video camera source + navigator.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, html5-video, getusermedia

I have a `video` element displaying a camera source being fed via `navigator.getUserMedia` (or relevant). How do I determine the codec being utilized to display the video source? I need this information to properly utilize `MediaSource.isTypeSupported()`.

Here is a full-page source of what I'm tinkering with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Display Webcam Stream &#38; Capture Image</title>
<script type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.onload = function(event)
{
 if (navigator.getUserMedia) {console.log('1, navigator.getUserMedia');navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);}
 else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {console.log('2, navigator.mozGetUserMedia');navigator.mozGetUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);}
 else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {console.log('3, navigator.webkitGetUserMedia');navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);}
 else if (navigator.msGetUserMedia) {console.log('4, navigator.msGetUserMedia');navigator.msGetUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);}
 else if (navigator.oGetUserMedia) {console.log('5, navigator.oGetUserMedia');navigator.oGetUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);}
 else {alert('Error: browser not supported?\n\n'+MediaDevices.getUserMedia());}
}


function handleVideo(stream)
{
 document.querySelector('#video_example').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}

function videoError(e) {
    // do something
}

function capture_image()
{
 var video  = document.querySelector('#video_example');
 var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 canvas.width  = video.videoWidth;
 canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(canvas);
}
//]]>
</script>  
<style>
#container {height: 768px; margin: 0px auto; width: 1024px;}
#video_example {height: 768px; width: 1024px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<video autoplay="true" id="video_example"></video>
<input onclick="capture_image();" type="button" value="Capture Image" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Mozilla's Developer Network (MDN) didn't seem to suggest anything of the likes exists?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: why do you need to know `MediaSource.isTypeSupported()` ?

Comment: @iownthegame Please restate your question. Though my guess is that it is why do I need to know the codec being used (it might be raw video, I'm not sure) as I'm trying to avoid the possibility of trying to convert the video stream from one codec to another when it's exceptionally unlikely to be a possibility.

Comment: sorry for confusing you, yes I mean why you need to know the codec of the video stream. BTW `navigator.getUserMedia()` is being Deprecated, try using   `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia. And basically the api allows you to deal with the `MediaStream` by passing itself to `window.URL.createObjectURL()` and assign to the `video.src`, so I think you don't need to worry about the codec. Moreover, you can use `MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` to check the available audio and video medias on your system